# Не передаются данные post в ASP.NET Web Api

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

файл контроллера

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using WebApiService.Models;

namespace WebApiService.Controllers
{
    public class ProductController : ApiController
    {
        public IEnumerable<Product> Get()
        {
            Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();
            return new List<Product> {
                new Product(0,"Game",12.4f),
                new Product(1,"Yana",1f),
                new Product(2,"Maggy",56f),
            };
        }

        public Product Post([FromBody]Product product)
        {
            // product = null
            return product;//don't work
        }
    }
}
```

Клиентское приложение

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApiService.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
           $.ajax({
                url: "/api/product",
                type: "POST",
                data:{id:12,name:"Gomer",price:12},
                contentType: "application/json",
            }).done(function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }).fail(function (err) {
                alert(err);
            });




        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Неправильно ajax написал, есть какие-то камни подводные?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**contentType** указывать не нужно
ну и насколько помню атрибут `[FromBody]` указывается только когда прилетает с формы а не `Json`, но могу и ошибаться

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
       var product = {id:12,name:"Gomer",price:12};
       $.ajax({
            url: '/api/product',
            type: 'POST',
            data:{product:product}
        }).success(function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }).error(function (err) {
            alert(err);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Всё равно null сервер получает( Get хорошо работает, не получаеться передавать данные серверу почему-то. Постоянно null or 0. Пробовал и с [frombody] и без, всё равно null... блин.

Comment: @WebWorkDeveloper завтра погляжу что и как, сегодня уже лень виртуалку опять запускать. Терпит?

Comment: @WebWorkDeveloper вот тут посмотрите, решенее вашего вопроса http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/web-api-with-ajax-understand-post-request-in-web-api/